# I no longer need my default site in my Firebase Project

Tags: firebase

Firebase hosting allows us to create multiple sites under a single hosting account, which is awesome. After extensive work, I am satisfied with my 2nd site that I created under my project, and no longer need the default site (circle in red).

Sense the default site can't be deleted by default in the browser, is there a way To either delete it, redirect it to another site in the same project, or disable it so that its not publicly visible on the web, all from the CLI command line?

I have red the guides, and I have tried...

1. adding targets to my configuration file
2. running the following command line: `firebase hosting:delete <default site>`

but no luck.

What have people done in this situation?

[image]

Comment: The primary (default) site for your Firebase project cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly you will have to disable the the site then only you will see the delete action.

You could run `firebase hosting: disable` through the `firebase-tools` CLI first. Then you will see a delete action under "three vertical dots".

Comment: For sanity sake, I updated my .firebaserc and firebase.json files to point to my desired site as the focus.  I then deployed these config settings to firebase. I then went back into my terminal and ran the firebase disable command you provided.  As a result my default site is disabled and my desired site within the same project, is still standing.  Many thanks on this!